# Where can I find libnotify1_0.5.0-2ubuntu1_i386.deb?

Tags: 11.10, package-management, thunderbird, notification, notify-osd

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10.  I am trying to install Thunderbird `8.0` and it keeps saying that it is dependent on `libnotify1 (>=0.5.0)`.

I find that libnotify1 is not installed in 11.10.  It is not listed in Ubuntu web sites as a download for 11.10. It does list it for 11.04.

Does anyone know can `libnotify1_0.5.0-2ubuntu1_i386.deb` be install in 11.10?  If not, how do I overcome the Thunderbird dependency issue?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: From where are you installing Thunderbird 8? If I can know about this, then providing the solution becomes more easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd wait for official ubuntu packages of thunderbird 8, it shouldn't take too long until those show up in the update-manager. 
Anyhow, if you really can't wait, you can install libnotify 0.7 manually from the official repositories. Just

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

If you're running 64bit Ubuntu and want the 32bit Thunderbird, you probably need the 32bit version of the library, which you can install by

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin:i386
```

Comment: I ran the "sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin" as you suggested and it came back and said "libnotify-bin is already the newest version"

Comment: To Manish Sinha

Comment: To Manish Sinha (I'll try again)  I am installing Tunderbird 8 from "http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu"

Comment: Check that the PPA you have selected for that is using the oneiric release, not natty.

Answer (score 0):

your thunderbird is not compatible with 11.10. 11.10 has libnotify4 (updated) default installed. So download latest version of thunderbird or search for ubuntu 11.10 compatible thunderbird

Answer (score 0):

Use this ppa for the latest stable version of mozilla thunderbird:

https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-stable